# Update columns whose vales return from a function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a trouble with updating the table with values which are return back from a user function, I couldn't know how to do it.

Enviroment:MsSql

```
 DECLARE @files TABLE  
 (  
  Id uniqueidentifier,  
  Name nvarchar(255),  
  FolderId uniqueidentifier,  
  IsCheckedOut bit,  
  CheckedOutBy nvarchar(50),  
  IsDeleted bit,  
  IsVirtual bit,  
  Content varbinary(MAX),
  FolderPath nvarchar(MAX),
  CultureCode varchar(16)
 ) 


  UPDATE @files   
 SET Content= (SELECT TOP 1 Content FROM fnGetFileContentById (@changeListId, Id, @autoRevert,@cultureCode,@defaultCultureCode)), 
CultureCode =  (SELECT TOP 1 CultureCode FROM fnGetFileContentById (@changeListId, Id, @autoRevert,@cultureCode,@defaultCultureCode)), 
     FolderPath=(SELECT TOP 1 FullPath FROM Folder WHERE Id= FolderId)
```

function script

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetFileContentById]        
(        
 @changeListId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,        
 @fileId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,        
 @autoRevert BIT,      
 @cultureCode VARCHAR(16),    
 @defaultCultureCode VARCHAR(16)    
)        
RETURNS @fileContent TABLE        
(        
 Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,        
 FileId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,        
 Content VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL,        
 [Version] INT NOT NULL,        
 ChangeListId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,        
 FileTypeId INT NOT NULL  ,      
 CultureCode VARCHAR(16)    
)
```

I don't want to rerun fnGetFileContentById function for updating CultureCode, How do I write this statement with one execution of  fnGetGileContentById

Comment: Is it Mysql or sql-server? If sql-server what version are using?

Comment: What is the return type of `fnGetFileContentById` function? is it a Table valued function or else?

Comment: its MsSql 2008. I also added the function declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE @files 
    SET Content=FileContent.Content,
    CultureCode =FileContent.CultureCode,
    FolderPath= folder.FullPath
FROM @files
    CROSS APPLY 
   ( 
        SELECT TOP 1 
            Content,
            CultureCode
        FROM 
            fnGetFileContentById(@changeListId, Id, @autoRevert,@cultureCode,@defaultCultureCode)
   ) FileContent
   CROSS APPLY
   (
        SELECT TOP 1 
            FullPath 
        FROM 
            Folder 
        WHERE 
            f.Id = FolderId
   ) AS folder
```